# Injective with finite discontinuities mapping from $\mathbb R^n$ to $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

As a continuation to the fully answered question:

[Injective and Integrable Mapping from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117609/injectiveintregrable-mapping-from-mathbb-r3-to-mathbb-r)

Does there exist an injective mapping $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow[0,1]$ that has only a finite number of discontinuities? Or maybe one can come with some topological claim showing it is impossible?

Comment: I extended my answer to injective maps $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow[0,1]$ is an injective map. Take any circle $C\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. If $f$ is continuous on $C$, then the restriction of $f$ to $C$ is a homeomorphism $C\to f(C)$ (because $C$ is compact), which is a contradiction, because $C$ minus any point is connected, while $f(C)$ minus any point in $f(C)\cap(\inf f(C),\sup f(C))$ is disconnected. This shows that $f$ has a discontinuity on any circle in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In particular, when $n>1$, the cardinality of the discontinuities is continuum.

**Added:** By a similar argument combined with the [Borsuk–Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem), the number of discontinuities of any injective map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is continuum.

Comment: Thanks! Please note that in the mentioned question (in that link), there is an example with only countably many discontinuities.

Comment: No, in the answer to the mentioned question the discontinuities lie on the union of boundaries of cubes, which is a two-dimensional object of cardinality continuum (and measure zero). As I proved above, there is no injective map with less than continuum many discontinuities.

Comment: In fact Gerald Edgar commented on your original question (in that link): "Cannot be done with countably many discontinuities." And you responded: "Right. and thanks for your answer. if this is indeed the problem, so make it zero measure of discontinuities." 

Comment: i agree i dont have a full understanding, but this will come with time... i'm doing my best

Comment: So, can we say this... if $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ has Hausdorff dimension ${}\lt n-1$, then $\mathbb R^n \setminus A$ is connected?

Comment: yes, I do understand now, many thanks!! btw when I practically want to use what we learnt here (especially in the previous question), I encounter a problem that $f(x)$ for some $x\in\mathbb R^n$ requires $nd$ digits to be represented numerically, when $d$ is the maximum number of digits in the elements of $x$. so this can be numerically unstable. I'm now trying to find such injective&integrable function that would be more numerically stable for computers.